# gcc gives error regarding color

Tags: c++, gcc, colors

Whenever I run a gcc/g++ command or even a ping command it always shows the following error.

```
gcc --colour=auto.c -lgraph -o --colour=auto
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--colour=auto.c’
```

I don't seem to understand the underlying cause of this problem. It never occurred before and this is stopping me from carrying out my tasks. **The first line is not a command that I ran. It's part of the error.**

Here is a picture,
[ping error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1tUF.png)

set command gives the following [output](http://pastebin.com/XPL5JzNZ)

Comment: problem in your bashrc?

Comment: I use zshrc which can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/m0LJXrxi)

Comment: even a `ping` command??? what do you _actually_ type?

Comment: I type,
    
    ping google.com

and it gives the error shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have solved this by removing a plugin(warhol) of oh-my-zsh completely. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong in your command.

- `--colour=auto.c`: I believe this should be `-fdiagnostics-color=auto`
- `-o --colour=auto`: this makes GCC write the output to the file  `--colour=auto`, I doubt that was the intention.
- there is no input file for GCC.

Try with a command like this:

```
gcc -fdiagnostics-color=auto -lgraph -o output-file input-file
```

where `input-file` are your *.c or *.o files.

Comment: This is the output when I run "gcc -v" only or "ping google.com". I am not executing any files.

Comment: Ok, something in you shell configuration is messed up. Does the problem go away when you open a new terminal?
Alternatively, can you post the output of the command `set` to pastebin?

Comment: No, it does not but if I switch to bash it does go away.

Comment: Your .zshrc includes many files, and the problem could be in any of them. Can you give us the output of `set` when you are in zsh?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the set command's output there. Please have a look

Comment: I'd try renaming the zsh config files (.zshenv, .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin) and check if the problem persists (after starting a new terminal, of course). If you manage to narrow down the problem to one of the config files, try finding the offending line by commenting out specific lines. I'd start with commenting out included external files (source or .)

Comment: Excellent! Please update your question with a short description of the solution, in order to help future readers of this page.
--edit Ok, I saw you did that already. Thanks.